# Best Stereo Camera that ROS Supports?

Tags: ros, stereo-camera, stereo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Users and developers,

I am looking to buy a stereo camera, specifically for outdoor self driving car applications such as mapping and localization probably by using ORB-SLAM2.

I found that ZED and Bumblebee are two of the options.

1. Could anyone say which Stereo camera(with ROS support) is the best one to get and their pros and cons ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287940/best-stereo-camera-that-ros-supports-?/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2018-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-09**:
I think this is a very difficult question to answer (the "best that ROS supports" one), as there are very few products that have such a range in performance as to be applicable to all imaginable application scenarios. Your question text adds some more info/constraints, but is still quite vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Personally, I don't have any experience with the Bumblebee. The ZED is IMO not very robust, especially in an outdoor context, which is mainly due to the somewhat limited FOV (again, outdoor context).

Considering your application (outdoor self driving car), I would actually go for the [Multisense S21](https://carnegierobotics.com/multisense-s21/). It has the far larger base length compared to the other two, is (thus) long-range and specifically designed for outdoor and "heavy-duty" use. Also, you can get different lenses...

Con: Price

(Then again, I'm no camera expert...)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2018-04-10**:
Thank you and this information is quite useful!

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2018-04-10**:
Checking online brought me to this link which might be useful for others https://rosindustrial.org/news/2016/1/13/3d-camera-survey